# Adding Harvard style reference in overleaf template

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

I'm trying to add Harvard style reference in an overleaf template

I have modified the article.tex available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/henriqueslab-biorxiv-template/nyprsybwffws) to include the following

```
\documentclass[times, twoside, watermark]{zHenriquesLab-StyleBioRxiv}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{thri,
        author = {Thirlwal, A. P.},
        year = {2011},
        title = {Economics of development: theory and evidence},
        edition = {9th},
        publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
        address = {New York}
    }
    @article{ahu61,
        author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
        title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
        journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
        volume={8},
        year = {1961},
        pages = {175-191}
    }
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{blindtext}

% Please give the surname of the lead author for the running footer
\leadauthor{Henriques} 

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{Henriques Lab bioRxiv template}
\shorttitle{My Template}

% Use letters for affiliations, numbers to show equal authorship (if applicable) and to indicate the corresponding author
\author[1,\Letter]{Ricardo Henriques}

\affil[1]{Quantitative Imaging and Nanobiophysics Group, MRC Laboratory for Molecular Cell Biology and Department of Cell and Developmental Biology, University College London, Gower Street, London, WC1E 6BT, United Kingdom}

\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor \parencite{ahu61} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
exports have been raised \parencite[42]{thri}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:
The pdf document generated doesn't contain the reference in Harvard style though.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor [1] sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.exports have been raised [2, p. 42].
```

Could someone please check the template available here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/henriqueslab-biorxiv-template/nyprsybwffws ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zHenriquesLab-StyleBioRxiv` document class loads `natbib` and uses a `zHenriquesLab-StyleBib.bst` file, so it can only be used with BibTeX, and is not compatible with `biblatex`. It looks like `zHenriquesLab-StyleBib.bst` file supports `natbib`'s author-year mode. ("Harvard" style is often just a generic catch-all term for author-year styles.)

If you remove the `biblatex` related commands from your document, and write `\setcitestyle{authoryear}` before `\begin{document}`, your citations and reference list will then become author-year.

You'll have to write `\citep{...}` to get parenthetical citation `(Smith, 2020)` and `\citet{...}` to get text citation `Smith (2020)`.

(When `natbib` is loaded with `authoryear` mode, `\cite` will behave like `\citet` by default. But it is best to avoid using `\cite` as @moewe pointed out in the comments: because it changes behaviour depending on whether or not there is a postnote argument, which can be quite confusing.)

Comment: +1 Though it's best not to use `\cite`, because it changes behaviour depending on whether or not there is a postnote argument, which can be quite confusing. The `natbib` documentation recommends only the use of `\citet` and `\citep`.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, I've updated my answer to include this note.